# Using XPath: find last text node of each paragraph under the root node

Tags: html, ruby, xpath, xhtml, rexml

I want to trim trailing whitespace at the end of all XHTML paragraphs. I am using Ruby with the REXML library.

Say I have the following in a valid XHTML file:

```
<p>hello <span>world</span> a </p>
<p>Hi there </p>
<p>The End </p>
```

I want to end up with this:

```
<p>hello <span>world</span> a</p>
<p>Hi there</p>
<p>The End</p>
```

So I was thinking I could use XPath to get just the text nodes that I want, then trim the text, which would allow me to end up with what I want (previous).

I started with the following XPath:

```
//root/p/child::text()
```

Of course, the problem here is that it returns all text nodes that are children of all p-tags. Which is this:

```
'hello '
' a '
'Hi there '
'The End '
```

Trying the following XPath gives me the last text node of the last paragraph, not the last text node of each paragraph that is a child of the root node.

```
//root/p/child::text()[last()]
```

This only returns: `'The End '`

What I would like to get from the XPath is therefore:

```
' a '
'Hi there '
'The End '
```

Can I do this with XPath? Or should I maybe be looking at using regular expressions (That's probably more of a headache than XPath)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your example worked for me

```
//p/child::text()[last()]
```

Comment: that only gets the last result though, he wants all of them throughout the document

Comment: no, it gives the exact dataset he was asking for. It returns the last child text element of every p (in this case, three of them)

Comment: @nickf: You are correct. When you said it worked, I went and double checked. In doing so, it shows that the problem seems to be with the Ruby REXML library's implementation of XPath. Well, I won't say that until I investigate further. Could be a setting I need to pass to REXML (or some such thing)

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I was using Ruby & REXML. I incorrectly assumed that XPath would be just XPath.

Comment: It looks like it is a bug in REXML.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you didn't know, XSL has a `normalize-space()` function which will get rid of leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can normalize-space() or a similar function, remove trailing spaces only (leaving any leading spaces alone)?